# Django Admin edit multiple models at once

Tags: python, django

I am trying to find a way to add/edit two models at once. i.e. :

```
class Desktop(models.Model):
    #some field...

    specs = models.ForeignKey(Specs)

class Specs(models.Model):
    cpu = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #and some other fields
```

When I add a new Desktop, I want to be able to add the Specs at the same time.
With the normal Django Admin you will get an `+` symbol, and you can add the values of the ForeignKey. But when you want to edit the foreignkey while editing the Desktop, you can't do it.

UPDATE!
I've added the following:

```
class ServerInLine(admin.StackedInLine): 
    model = Server 
    extra = 1  
class SpecsManager(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    inlines = [ServerInLine]
```

This makes me able to add an server when adding Specs. But actually I want to add Specs when I add a new Server. So when I add a new Server or Desktop, I want to add the specs. The specs field in Server and Desktop should then link to the specs filled in.

Comment: There is no easy write up I could give you to show you how to do this but instead I'll refer to the Django documents. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Comment: Can your add your `admin.py`?

Answer (score 5):

Try this in your admin:

```
 class DesktopInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Desktop
    extra = 1


class SpecsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DesktopInline,]
admin.site.register(Specs, SpecsAdmin)
```

take a look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)

Comment: Sorry for not saying it. I've got the model Desktop which needs specs. But I also want to make an model called Server who needs specs. Thats why I made an model for Specs. So when people want to add a Desktop they can add specs. And when they add a Server they can also add Specs.

Comment: You can do it with server the same way I did, see the docs for more info

Comment: At this moment i've got the following:

    class ServerInLine(admin.StackedInLine):
        model = Server
        extra = 1

    class SpecsManager(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [ServerInLine]

This makes me able to add an server when adding Specs. But actually I want to add Specs when I add a new Server. So when I add a new Server or Desktop, I want to add the specs. The specs field in Server and Desktop should then link to the specs filled in.

Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: would you please update your question with this and make sure its well formatted, its hard to read it that way

Comment: I dont think you can,it works only one way because the foreignkey is in desktop and server not in specs

Comment: Thanks for the help though :). I am going to re-construct the data model.